# Configuring Video Capturing Open CV

Tags: python, opencv

In my program, I am using the video capture function to read a video from file and display it onto a window. I am successfully displaying the video, but the video is in slow motion and full screen. The issue is that I am trying to set the window to a custom dimension and trying to play the video at a normal pace, but neither attempts are working. Here is my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.path)
cap.set(3, 530)      # width
ret = cap.set(4, 450)      # height

try:
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)  
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        cv2.waitKey(20)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
except:
    print("error")

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Any ideas on how to fix my program to play at a normal pace and to follow the dimensions that I am trying to impose?

Update: I have tried both suggested methods as shown in the following code:
flag = cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL
       cv2.namedWindow('winName', flag)

```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.path)

   cap.set(3, 500)      
   cap.set(4, 500)     
   try:
       while(cap.isOpened()):

           ret, frame = cap.read()
           frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)   # bart
           gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
           cv2.imshow('winName', gray)
           if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
               break

   except:
       print("error")

   cap.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   cv2.waitKey(1)
   cv2.waitKey(1)
   cv2.waitKey(1)
   cv2.waitKey(1)
```

However, the program is still not functioning as sizable and is not playing back the video at a normal rate. Any other ideas?

Comment: videocapture from files doesnt handle the timing, it just provides the images. remove cv2.waitKey(20) to make it faster

Comment: Hi, I removed the delay, but the video continues to play at a slow pace. Any other ideas?

Comment: that means you cant render the images faster with imshow. try to implement a faster rendering with opengl for example

Comment: and/or video decoding is too slow. try to write all images to an array before starting the playback

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the playing video is based on `cv2.waitKey()` (in another word the delay) that you use. I think if you remove the `cv2.waiKey(20)` it should be played in normal speed (the waitkey() in the if loop is enough).

If you want to change the size of the window that is showing the video, you should first create a window, than show the image in it.

```
cv2.namedWindow('winName', flag)
```

the flag can be `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` so you can change the size, or `cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` so the window fits the video size (when you don't use `namedWindow()` the flag is automatically set to `cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` so you cant change the size). Than Show your frame in it

```
cv2.imshow('winName', gray)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this configuration, but it is still not letting me dimension the window.

Comment: Take a look at these links, they may help you [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) and [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow). By the way, I tested your code and it's working with no problem